# Laravel's alias loader does not find class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

We have a legacy project that we cannot update and we need to make some changes in symfony's `Response.php` in vendor. We have solved this by copying `Response.php` to a separate folder and using an alias to load that new class instead of vendor's. We did this in `AppServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot()
    {
        AliasLoader::getInstance()->alias('Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response', 'App\Overrides\Response');
...

public function provides()
    {
        return ['Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response'];
```

It worked fine until we pushed to production and suddenly it stopped working. While it still works fine on our `dev` servers. We can clearly see that the original class from vendor is being loaded instead of the one from `Overrides` so for some reason the alias doesn't work. Does anyone have any clue as to what could cause this? Don't even know where to start or what sorts of settings or artisan commands could have caused this behaviour.

**Update:** After further investigation, it seems that artisan optimize is the culprit. On our dev servers the Response class is being served from Overrides folder, but on production it's served from optimized.php cache. Even though both servers run optimize.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my laravel website. To fix it, in my composer.json files, in the script section i add the following commands :

```
    "scripts": {
        "pre-install-cmd": [
            "@php -r \"unlink('bootstrap/cache/services.php');\"",
            "@php -r \"unlink('bootstrap/cache/config.php');\""
        ],
        "pre-autoload-dump": [
            "@php -r \"array_map('unlink', glob('bootstrap/cache/*'));\""
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ],
    }
```

Those commands will remove some cache from previous version release in production and discover new packages. I hope it helps.